# Elmah add message to error logged through call to Raise(e)

Tags: c#, .net, elmah, error-logging

I'm a bit confused at how to add a message to an error logged programatically with ELMAH.

eg:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(int id)
{
    try { ... }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // I want to include the 'id' param value here, and maybe some
        // other stuff, but how?
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
    }
}
```

It seems all Elmah can do is log the raw exception, how can I also log my own debug info?

Comment: curious why Elmah doesn't have an overload for Raise for additional messages. contextual information is vital when trying to fix certain errors

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can throw a new Exception setting the original as the inner exception and ELMAH will log the messages for both:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    Exception ex = new Exception("ID = 1", e);
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
}
```

will show

```
System.Exception: ID = 1 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: you should use Exception.Data, but by default elmah does not have this functionality. I added to a custom version I use. I really should post the code up somewhere. I know this is old but I think this is not 100% correct. Yes you can use this for small details, but if you want a list of data that's what the Exception.Data was made for. For example when an SQLException is thrown you get a lot of details. I also added this. It's not really hard to do yourself. Also when working with linq2sql you can also get a lot of details.

Answer (score 3):

I found that I can also do something like:

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new NotImplementedException("class      FbCallback.Page_Load() Request.Url= " + Request.Url));
```

To log my own messages.  Then in when I browse to

```
http://localhost:5050/elmah.axd
```

I see my messages as type NotImplementedException.
Not very pretty but works.